# elasticsearch always returns null-result while querying

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

I'm trying to learn elasticsearch following [Getting Started](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html). But always I get `null` result when querying except `match_all`.

When I execute `match_all`query like below, it works fine:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
      "match_all": {}
  }
}'  | head -20
```

Output(1):

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{
  "took" : 15,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "acount",
      "_id" : "_buck",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"account_number":6,"balance":5686,"firstname":"Hattie","lastname":"Bond","age":36,"gender":"M","address":"671 Bristol Street","employer":"Netagy","email":"hattiebond@netagy.com","city":"Dante","state":"TN"}
curl: (23) Failed writing body (8282 != 16384)
```

Next I execute `match` and other commands like `filter`, `aggr`, `size`,

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
      "match": {"age": 32}
  }
}'  | head -20
```

Output(2):

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   261  100   193  100    68  31535  11111 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 38600
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Why the `hits.hits = [ ]` in output(2) ? According to output(1), Amber's age is `32`, isn't it ?

Comment: This is strange behaviour, can you post the mapping? If the age is a long this should work. If it somehow became a float, other things can happen.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Oh that reminded me ! I never check the mapping.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Oh that reminded me ! I have never check the mapping. I checked the mapping and I found maybe I make mistakes when loaded data. And it works fine after recreating a new cluster and reloading data. Thank you !